# How to capture a subdomain in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract the username from a tumblr. That is, the regex should match `asdf` in the following test string:

```
https://asdf.tumblr.com/
http://asdf.tumblr.com/faq
www.asdf.tumblr.com/
asdf.tumblr.com
```

Basically, I think I need to do something like, match from either a dot or a slash until the next dot, but I'm having trouble making it work in every case. Currently I have this:

```
.*[\/|\.](.*)\.tumblr\.com.*
```

However, this fails to capture the last group (`asdf.tumblr.com`). I tried modifying it to no avail. Can this be done?

Comment: Why not use an URL parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex in Javascript:

```
/[^.\/]+(?=\.tumblr\.com)/i
```

[RegEx Demo](http://[%5E.%5C/]+(?=%5C.tumblr%5C.com))

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^.\/]+`: Match 1 or more of any character that is not `.` and `/`
- `(?=\.tumblr\.com)`: Positive lookahead to ensure we have `.tumblr.com` at next position

**Code:**

```js
let x = /([^.\/]+)(?=\.tumblr\.com)/;
let y = "https://asdf.tumblr.com";

console.log( y.match(x)[1] );
```

Comment: Hey cool thanks! Sorry if this is asking too much, but is it possible to make the capture be capture group 1 and not a full capture? Basically, I have this username extraction working on other domains with other regexes and they all use `$1` to refer to the first capture group, and I'd like to have consistent logic between all of them, if that makes sense. Edit: Oh, I think maybe you just need to surround the beginning in parenthesis, like this? `/([^.\/]+)(?=\.tumblr\.com)/i` ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe not. This is not returning `asdf`: `let x = /([^.\/]+)(?=\.tumblr\.com)/g; let y = "https://asdf.tumblr.com"; console.log(y.replace(x, '$1'));` I think it's because the full match should be the entire string. Nevermind, I'll figure it out. If I have any more trouble i'll ask another question.

Comment: You don't need to call `.replace`. Just use `.match`

Comment: Ah right what was I thinking. Thanks! Works perfectly now.